# Angular custom directive basic input filter not working properly, only show 1st instance of match

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-datalist

I am writing a custom directive for input field , when you start typing, it will show a filtered list that would match what you are typing:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('AnimateCtlr', function($scope){
  $scope.data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'strawberry'];
    $scope.filteredData = [];
})
.directive('basicInputFilter', function($filter){
  var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {


        element.on('input', function(event, combo, selection){
             var expression = $(this).text();
             expression = scope.filter;
             console.log(expression);
             scope.$apply(function(){

                scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')(scope.data, expression);
             });
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            data:'=',
            filteredData:'=',
            filter: '='
        }
    };
});
```

From what i observed, it will only show the 1st instance of matching, not all possible matching result, and will show no result if matching is not first letter. What can be wrong here?

Plunker is : http://plnkr.co/edit/REDJywQljTmtv2d3ZnD2?p=preview

Comment: could you look at this http://jjperezaguinaga.com/2013/09/18/angularjs-html5-autocomplete/

Comment: tried that. now the drop down list disappear really quickly. can't select anything.

Comment: @WABBIT0111 Seems like it is functioning correctly. Maybe i am misunderstanding your intent of usage. If you add more items starting with the letter "A" it will retrieve all items that start with "A", when you type "A". Are you expecting it to show everything and just sort the "A" to the top?

Comment: @kcbeard: when you type "a", it should show you all the instance that contains "a", not necessarily starting with "a". There are problems here that i observe:1st,  it only display 1 match, the top match, on drop down, and ideally it should display all match.

Comment: @WABBIT0111 if you add say, "artichoke", "asparagus" . it will return all that start with a. You need it to return all items containing a sounds like.

Comment: @kcbeard  yes, i need all the items containing "a". in fact, if you look at the console logs for "scope.filteredData", everything that contains "a" are there in the array, but somehow, it's not displaying in the dropdown.

Comment: Yeah i saw that scope.filteredData has the correctly filtered items if you inspect the element. They are all there. The options are not getting re-rendered "visually" though.

Comment: do you suggest $compile function, and take that <datalist> inside the directive as template?

Comment: After reading http://htmlcssjavascript.com/javascript/easy-autocomplete-with-the-datalist-element-the-list-attribute-and-angularjss-ng-repeat-directive/  and  https://coderwall.com/p/0lms3g/angularjs-html5-autocomplete. I think you may want to find a better solution. All the eamples behave this way. Though i did see http://jsfiddle.net/lukers/MCnL2/  which did not. So i would like to hear what your final resolution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular, but with how the browsers implement the datalist element.

For example, last time I checked, Chrome, Opera and IE all filter based on "starts with", while Firefox uses "contains".

This means that it doesn't matter if you use `$filter` to set up the correct option elements, since when the user types in the input, the browser will apply its own filter on top of that.

I strongly recommend to move away from datalist for now and instead look for a library that implements the features you need in an autocomplete element.